# How to enable Realtek 8188ee driver on CentOS 6.7?

Tags: linux, centos, realtek

Unfortunately I installed CentOS 6.7 on a basic HP laptop without checking the wifi capability... which is a Realtek rtl8188EE. I've done some research on that particular driver which seems to have gone away. I'm about to try an rtl8188CE, and go from there. I'd already installed CentOS 7 on the box which actually did recognize the driver automatically. Which is great, except that I realized that I didn't really want to go to 7 yet because we only have RHEL 6 at work and need the OS cheaply (!) to work on my cert at home. So I went back to 6.7. Anyway without going out and buying a whole 'nother laptop, anyone ever had any luck with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `rtl8188efw.bin` firmware file to be somewhere in `/lib/firmware`.

If it isn't packaged for Centos 6.7, you can get it (along with a lot of other firmware) with:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dwmw2/linux-firmware.git
```

Then copy it into `/lib/firmware/`

BTW, on my debian system, it is in the `firmware-realtek` package with filename `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin`

If it isn't being automatically loaded at boot time (it should be), you also need to ensure that the `rtl8188ee` kernel module is being loaded.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Hopefully I can get it done this weekend; I'd searched around git but hadn't come up with this particular firmware. I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: This is really old, sorry but I haven't gotten to this yet! It sounds like what I need to do, thanks! I'll mark this answered.